# How to check or activate SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mediawiki-extensions

During Mediawiki installation I checked the option for SyntaxHighlight, and it created a LocalSettings line,

```
   wfLoadExtension( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi' );
```

so, I am supposed that it was installed... But no examples for `<source lang>` tag is running. For instance the [example of the Guide page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight),
 `<syntaxhighlight lang="Python" line='line'> def quickSort(arr): ...</syntaxhighlight>`  
and its variations (with `<source>` tag) are not working.

- How to check if its alive?
- How to activate or to complete the installation?

Comment: Check ->special pages->Version, and see if extension appears in the list.

Comment: Thanks @IRA1777, the Version page shows *SyntaxHighlight 2.0*, so thats is the answer for the first subquestion (!), seems it is alive.   It only cite on the description the tag `<syntaxhighlight>` (not tag "source"), but my cited (above) test with  `lang="Python"` is not working and generated a category of error message.

Answer (score 1):

When installed on Linux, GeSHi requires the pygmentize binary to be marked executable (in the **{wiki_installed_folder}/extensions/SyntaxHightlight_GeSHi** folder) - by default that property might not be set.

Run "**chmod +x pygmentize**" to mark it executable - make sure to set the other read/write flags appropriately - to avoid any security issues.